# Changing wallpaper image from Listview android

Tags: android-listview

Please excuse my English!
I am very new to android studio.I created a list view showing different images.I want the wallpaper to show the image in the list view when double clicked
I cannot set the Resource

```
                final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setResource();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```